Hamiltonian under the transformation induced by its own flow
Suppose we have a Hamiltonian $H(q,p)$ that leads to the flow:
$$
\begin{cases}
q=q(Q,P,t) \\[2mm]
p=p(Q,P,t)
\end{cases}
$$
where $P=p(0)$ and $Q=q(0)$ are the initial conditions.
I noticed that substituting $q(Q,P,t)$ and $p(Q,P,t)$ inside $H$ I get an expression for $P,Q$ only that has the same form as $H(q,p)$, i.e. I get $H(Q,P)$.
If this holds always, what can be an elementary way to prove this fact?
Would this hold also for time dependent Hamiltonians $H(p,q,t)$?
I think that a possible explanation stems from the fact that $P=p(0)$ and $Q=q(0)$ and that at least in the time invariant case the $t$ goes away as the Hamiltonian has to stay time independent in the transformed system (as it is a canonical transformation), but I am not able to formalize this and I would prefer a simpler explanation.

Consider a solution of the Hamilton equations $x=x(t)$ with $x(0)=x_0$. By direct inspection,using the very Hamilton equations
$$\frac{d}{dt} H(x(t)) = \sum_{k} \frac{\partial H}{\partial q^k} \frac{dq^k}{dt}+ \sum_{k} \frac{\partial H}{\partial p_k} \frac{dp_k}{dt} + \frac{\partial H}{\partial t}= 0+\frac{\partial H}{\partial t}|_{x(t)}=0\:.$$
As a consequence
$$H(x(t)) = H(x(0))\:.$$
With your notation
$$H(q,p)= H(Q,P)\:.$$

thanks! how does this change in case $H$ does depend on $t$?

In that case the new Hamiltonian (that it is not the one obtaioned by composing the initial Hamiltonian with the canonical flow of time-evolution) remains "invariant in form". But this issue is much more delicate.

I think I found an Hamiltonian for which substituting $P$ and $Q$ does not lead to the same form: $H=pq+pt+qt$.  I find that the Hamilton equations give $p = (P-1)e^{-t}- t +1$
$q = (Q+1)e^t-  t  -1$ so substituing in $H$ gives me $P Q - P e^{-t} + P + Q e^t - Q - t^2 + e^{-t} + e^t - 2$ which has different form.
However, I understand that this is in agreement with your last comment, as this is not the "new" Hamiltonian? What do we mean by new Hamiltonian then?

Sorry, I took a mistake, I was thinking to the case where the generator of the continuous symmetry is parametrically depending on time AND the Hamiltonian does not. Instead we are here considering the case where the generator and the Hamiltonian coincide and also parametrically depends on time.

no problem and thanks for the clarification. so, unless I did some mistake in my computation one comment above, for a time dependent Hamiltonian, the substitution $p=p(P,Q,t)$,$q=(P,Q,t)$ does not necessarily give a $H(P,Q)$ with the same form as $H(p,q)$, correct?
